# Can we have more workers than number of cores in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, worker

I have a `Core i7` CPU and `4 real cores`. Can I have more than `4 workers` for my computation or the number of workers are always equal to the cores number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be able to have 8 workers, because the 4 cores have hyper threading, giving you 8 logical cores. But, because there are only 4 physical cores, 8 workers shouldn't be much faster than 4 workers in theory.
However, I did find that 6 and 8 workers were faster than 4 on my i7.

To do this try

```
matlabpool open 8;
parfor I = 1:N
    #your code
end
```

EDIT: in R2014a `matlabpool` is being replaced with `parpool`, so use this instead:

```
parpool('local', 8);
parfor I = 1:N
    #your code
end
```

to open 8 cores on your local machine.

Note: you only need to run the `matlabpool` command once, when Matlab starts up. Then you can run many scripts with parfor loops in them without opening the workers again, they will stay open until you close them or close Matlab.

This should open 8 workers on your local system.

If you get an error about the number of available workers then you need to change a setting:
Parallel menu -> Manage Configurations. Right-click on the "local" line. In the scheduler tab, set the "Number of workers available to scheduler" to 8.

Finally, you can only have one pool of workers open at a time, use this:

```
poolobj = gcp('nocreate');
delete(poolobj);
```

to close an open pool. Then you can try and open another pool with more workers.

Comment: To check if you have hyper threading enabled (i.e. 8 logical cores) open the Task Manager and go to the performance tab, you should see 8 graphs in the CPU usage history. (Windows only)

Comment: + what is default number of workers that `MATLAB` is using for `core i7`?

Comment: I have this error : You requested a minimum of 8 workers, but the cluster "local" has the NumWorkers property set to allow a
maximum of 4 workers. To run a communicating job on more workers than this (up to a maximum of 512 for the
Local cluster), increase the value of the NumWorkers property for the cluster. The default value of
NumWorkers for a Local cluster is the number of cores on the local machine.

Comment: Now I have this error ! : `Found an interactive session. You cannot have multiple interactive sessions open simultaneously. To
terminate the existing session, use 'delete(gcp)'`.

Comment: You should be able to set the default number of cores in the settings menu I mention in the answer, as far as I can remember.